# Folder name with space issue

Tags: perl

How do I handle a folder name containing spaces in Perl? For example `C:\Sample Picture\Data`.

I wrote this

```
use File::Glob ':glob';

$indir = "C:\\Sample Picture\\Data\\";

@flist =  bsd_glob( $indir.'*');
```

This is throwing an error

> The syntax of the command is incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message `The syntax of the command is incorrect` comes from the Windows command line, not from Perl

The issue is not to do with `File::Glob`, but with whatever you are doing with the contents of `@flist`. It's my guess that you're using backticks or `system` to rename one or more of the files or directories. This will fail if you use paths that contain spaces without enclosing the complete path in double quotes

If you need any more help then you must show the relevant part of your code

Comment: Thank you Borodin,  its the problem with the system function like you said,I just changed and it worked

Comment: @shinoy.m: Note that you should be using the Perl `rename` operator in preference to starting a whole new process just to rename a file.

Comment: [`move`](http://p3rl.org/File::Copy#move) is the better working `rename`. [File::Copy is in core.](http://perlpunks.de/corelist/mversion?module=File%3A%3ACopy)